# How can I get text only from the current node with DOMElement?

Tags: php, dom-node

```
<div>
     <a>abc</a>
     xyz
</div>
```

Given the above HTML structure, `$divElement->nodeValue` returns 'abc xyz', when I want to get 'xyz' only. `$divElement->getAttribute('value')` is empty.

How can I get 'xyz' without removing the `<a>` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate through the `<div>` and combine all text node:

http://3v4l.org/fnTAF

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(<<<HTML
<div>
     <a>abc</a>
     xyz
</div>
HTML
);
$div=$dom->getElementsByTagName("div")->item(0);
var_dump($div->childNodes->length);//just to debug
$txt="";
foreach(range(0,$div->childNodes->length-1) as $idx)
{
    if($div->childNodes->item($idx)->nodeType==3)
    {
        $txt.=$div->childNodes->item($idx)->nodeValue;
    }
}
var_dump($txt);
```

`nodeType==3` means text node. The corresponding `nodeName` is `#text`.

Comment: `foreach(range(0,$div->childNodes->length-1) as $idx)` is unnecessary ninja coding. The good old "for" hits the case: `for( $idx = 0; $idx < $div->childNodes->length; ++$idx )`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div>` actually has three children: one `text` node, one `<a>` node and another `text` node. At least that's what the XML standard says.
The first text node contains the white space between `<div>` and `<a>`. The second one contains your `xyz`.

If you inspect `$divElement->childNodes`, I believe you should get those two nodes, and you can make a distinction between the two.

Comment: No, it has actually _three_ children: The whitespace between `<div>` and `<a…` is a text node as well.